# creating controllers in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two **views** named **hello.jsp** and **hello_new.jsp**. Does it mean that I need to create two seperate controllers as

**hello.java**

```
@Controller
public class hello {
    @RequestMapping("/hello_new")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World_new, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println(message);
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

and 
**hello_new.java**

```
@Controller
public class Hello_new {
    @RequestMapping("/hello_new")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World_new, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println(message);
        return new ModelAndView("hello_new", "message", message);
    }
}
```

or is there any way creating a single controller can map this two views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to create different controller. Just create one controller and have multiple methods to handle different URL.

```
@Controller
public class hello {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println(message);
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello_new")
    public ModelAndView helloWorldNew() {
        String message = "Hello World_new, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println(message);
        return new ModelAndView("hello_new", "message", message);
    }
}
```